# How to send raw data as payload with MQTT on Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, mqtt

I want to send just raw data to the broker but the string is sent as string with quotations.

i.e.
the message I want to sent is: `ti=0F:0000000000&id=E8EB1BE99345`
but what is sent is: `"ti=0F:0000000000&id=E8EB1BE99345"`

How can I achieve that?

I have declared serializer in the mqtt client like below,

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'MQTT_CLIENT',
        transport: Transport.MQTT,
        options: {
          url: 'mqtt://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1883',
          clientId: 'my-client-id',
          serializer: {
            serialize: (value: any) => value.data,
          },
        },
      },
    ]),
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can see here that the ACKs are sent with the quotations, and they should be sent like above, without them:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to receive the messages? Are you sure it's not just a presentation artefact?

Comment: I'm using mqtt explorer to see the messages, with nestjs the response is a quoted string, with other clients it's just raw data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this behaviour is something standard in Nestjs, the publishing response will be returned as the result object of applying JSON.stringify().

There's no way of configure it anyhow.

The only option for doing that is to [create a custom ClientProxy](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport#client-proxy) or even easier [extend from ClientMqtt](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/client/client-mqtt.ts) and then override the **publish** method, so all the logic related with serialization is ignored, and just publish the **raw data** of the packet.

Custom class with the modified publish method:

```js
import { ClientMqtt, ReadPacket, WritePacket } from '@nestjs/microservices';

export class RawPayloadProxy extends ClientMqtt {
  protected publish(
    partialPacket: ReadPacket,
    callback: (packet: WritePacket) => any,
  ): () => void {
    try {
      const pattern = this.normalizePattern(partialPacket.pattern);

      const responseChannel = this.getResponsePattern(pattern);
      let subscriptionsCount =
        this.subscriptionsCount.get(responseChannel) || 0;

      const publishPacket = () => {
        subscriptionsCount = this.subscriptionsCount.get(responseChannel) || 0;
        this.subscriptionsCount.set(responseChannel, subscriptionsCount + 1);
        this.mqttClient.publish(
          this.getRequestPattern(pattern),
          partialPacket.data,
        );
      };

      if (subscriptionsCount <= 0) {
        this.mqttClient.subscribe(
          responseChannel,
          (err: any) => !err && publishPacket(),
        );
      } else {
        publishPacket();
      }

      return () => {
        this.unsubscribeFromChannel(responseChannel);
      };
    } catch (err) {
      callback({ err });
    }
  }
}
```

Definition of the custom client class on AppModule:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'MQTT_CLIENT',
        customClass: RawPayloadProxy,
        options: {
          url: 'mqtt://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1883',
          clientId: 'client-xxx',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```